# How can I regain program control after <cfheader> opens a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

This is a ColdFusion 8 question.

I have a cfm page that has a button that onClick calls the following Javascript function located in the page header:

```
function confirm_expiration_letters() {
    var resultOfConfirm = confirm("Would you like to send expiration and reminder letters?");
    if (resultOfConfirm == true) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
        window.location="_expiration_letters.cfm";
    }
}
```

On the page that is called, a series of emails are generated, then a PDF report file is generated and displayed using these two lines:

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#fileName#">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#docPath#/#fileName#" deletefile="true">
```

Notice in the JS function that the cursor is changed to "wait". But the program control appears to get lost after the above cfheader call and so I can't find anywhere that I can reset the cursor back to:
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";

Do you have ideas on where I can place this to turn off the cursor animation? I tried multiple places and it doesn't work. Once the cfheader and cfcontent calls happen, control of previous window and cursor are lost it appears.

Comment: ick... 10 points for the most obscure problem I've seen this week :)

Comment: what happens to the cursor? does it stay with the wait cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this above the cfheader.

```
<script>
document.body.style.cursor = "default";
</script>
<cfflush/>
```

The problem is that doing so might (probably will) screw up the cfheaders since cfflush is designed to flush partial results and will include the headers. But it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Yes according to CF reference for cfheader, putting a cfflush above it will throw an error. :(  Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: that's what I figured.  How about targeting a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the cursor, display a loading message using HTML/animated gif.  When the PDF loads, it will replace the loading screen.

I would suggest having a hidden div containing your loading message, then use JavaScript to make it appear when needed.

Here's some JavaScript.  This is how it would be done with jQuery.

```
function confirm_expiration_letters() {
var resultOfConfirm = confirm("Would you like to send expiration and reminder letters?");
if (resultOfConfirm == true) {
    $('#Loading').fadeIn(); //SHOW THE LOADING INDICATOR
    $.post('PDFGenerator.cfm', function(returnData){  // AJAX POST, CALLBACK
        //RETURN THE FILENAME OR LOCATION OF THE PDF
        var FileName = $.trim(returnData); // TRIM THE RETURNED DATA
        window.open("path_to_file/" + FileName,"_blank"); // NEW WINDOW
        $('#Loading').fadeOut();  // HIDE THE LOADING INDICATOR
      });
}
```

}

Comment: The cfheader/cfcontents cause the report to load in a PDF which triggers Adobe Reader (for my situation) to load it. I see a prompt to open it or cancel, opening loads it in Reader. I think the problem would still be present which is program control never returns to the originating page once that cfheader fires. Maybe I misunderstand your suggestion Josh.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't fully understand your concerns and the experience you are trying to create.  I think I have done what you are trying to do by making an AJAX request to the PDF generating page, have the PDF generation save the file to the server, then use a callback when the AJAX request completes to open the PDF in a new browser window.  The PDF will open and the user will stay on the requesting page.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Would you be able to provide some code snippets to illustrate this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a "wait" cursor whilst the PDF is prepped, and then return to a standard cursor after that.

Don't web browsers do this automatically when you're waiting for a requested document?  IE: as soon as you do your window.location, whilst the document is loading, the cursors automatically changes to a "wait", and then once the doc is served, returns to an "auto".

This is what I see (when running code similar to yours).  Is this *not* what you see?

Comment: Yes that is correct Adam.
I did remove the JS line document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
but while the PDF generation code itself current (in my sandbox) takes a split second to produce, I inserted a "sleep" of 5 seconds prior to that and I see no cursor change from the default arrow mode during the wait.  So unless my CF induced sleep is viewed as not a legit browser event to trigger the "wait" mode, I'm not seeing a dealy trigger a wait cursor automatically.